# How to specify a unique identifier for each thread in SL4J log message

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

Is there any way to specify a unique identifier for each log messages emitted by a specific thread using slf4j.Logger

For example, if I have ten worker threads executed in a thread pool , I want each thread to specify its identifier before each log message.

Currently I need to write something like this

```
final String marker ="SomeIdentifier" 
LOG.info("[{}] Connected to Socket: {}/{}", new Object[]{marker,ipAddr,port});
==> output
INFO - [pool-1-thread-1] [SomeIdentifier] Connected to Socket: rtdevslo2/7777
```

Is there any recommended way to do this using slf4j and log4j  ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use thread pool executors, the easiest way is to give [a custom ThreadFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) to your thread pool where you customise the name of the thread.

For example, most factory methods in `Executors` offer this option ([example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29)).

Typical implementation:

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
    private final AtomicInteger threadId = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r, "Socket Thread Pool - Thread # " + threadId.incrementAndGet());
    }
});
```